# How to set gas price in Remix IDE?

Tags: go-ethereum, remix, metamask, ropsten, docker

I'm testing my contract on Ropsten network.
For this i've launched geth in docker:

```
> command: --verbosity 4 -rpc --ipcdisable --rpcaddr "0.0.0.0" --rpccorsdomain "*"  --syncmode "fast"  --rpcapi="db,personal,eth,net,web3,admin" --cache=${CACHE_SIZE:-512} --testnet
```

I'm able to connect to it with:

> get attach http://127.0.0.1:8545

When trying to test my contract in Remix i've changed environment:

[image]

How can i set gas price to debug my smart contract calls?
Should i change my geth run arguments? Should i unlock my coinbase account before smart contract method calls?

BTW i've found that it working incorrectly. I loaded previously deployed in ropsten smart contract and i expect some specific result for method call (just reading current value). I have expected result with Metamask switched to Ropsten instead of geth. With geth i always get default value (0).